# external caching of pages with rails, multiple perspectives on the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, dry

I am looking to make the content of a url have several different views depending on the user's role and solving external caching issues, say the client's browser or a dumb proxy.

The URL is:

http://myhost.com/widget/1234

If the owner of widget 1234 looks at the page, they will see an "edit" and "stats" section..

If a non-logged in person views the same URL, they will see the page without the "owner" sections.

Since the same URL is being used, what is the best way handle this situation?  I suspect, that if the person is logged in, then they should see a different URL:

http://myhost.com/owners/widget/1234

Which will solve the caching issues quite nicely.  However, that messes up rail's resources view point.

Do I duplicate and tell Mr. DRY "sorry!"

Does anyone have any suggestions or advise?

-daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use presenters.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch

From there, you can create logic like

```
if user_signed_in?
  render 'blah'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

So right off the bat the easiest way to solve this is to have a separate page for admin roles vs a common user. So they have to go through a different manner to edit the page.

If it has to be on the same page their are one of two things you can do.

a) fragment cache the page and exclude parts that are user specific
b) use ajax to hit an end point that clarifies the roles. So basically by default you will hide the buttons and make an ajax request to /api/owners/roles that will determine for the current logged in user what their roles are. If they have greater then x role $(".edit-button").show()